# Is Hobgoblin a good substitute for Newcastle Brown in a beef stew recipe?

Tags: slow-cooking, stews, beer

I've bought some beer called Hobgoblin. I was going to buy Newcastle Brown as the ingredients in my recipe say brown ale. However, someone in the supermarket said Hobgoblin was not a brown ale. So what I want to know is, is this Hobgoblin any good in the stew or should I buy another type? If so which?

Comment: Pretty well any beer except lager will be OK in a stew.  Guinness is a good beer for beef stew, essentially the darker the beer the better.  I think Hobgoblin is a better choice than Newcastle Brown, its a richer beer.

Comment: Of course it all depends on your tastes. I don't use beer at all in my stews, I use wine. Just saying, this because lager can be just fine to use depending on what profile you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @user23614 agree that a budweiser or similarly pale flavourless lager would be no good for a stew, but there are lagers that would work fine. I've cooked with [this](http://steelandoak.ca/) dark lager before, was nice :)

Comment: The dark lagers would indeed be fine, I didn't think about them as they are quite rare in the UK, some of the ones I've tasted have been quite sweet though.

Comment: You might also want to try [trappist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trappist_beer) for stews (see also [dubbel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dubbel) and [tripel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tripel)). There tends to be some sweetness to them that you may want to balance out, but they work quite nicely.

Answer (score 6):

Hobgoblin is a dark brown ale and would work just fine as a replacement for Newcastle Nut Brown Ale for cooking purposes. Newcastle is more widely available than Hobgoblin, so is often used in recipes, but at the end of the day, any decent brown ale will do.